# Как задать иконке закруглённый фон?

Tags: css, img

[image: Здание]
  Как сделать такую же ерись как на картинке ?

Comment: Добавьте свой код

Answer (score 3):

Вот с использованием font-awesome

```css
i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: red;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background-color: white
}

div.bg{
  width: 31px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg">
  <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="business">
                   <div class="icon-bg"><img src="Img/Content/Business-icon.png" alt="Buisness"></div>
                    <p>12000<sup>+</sup><br>
                    Business</p>
                </div>.business {
     width: 400px; height: 150px;
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #80d8ff;
};Я не имею доступа к font-awesome так что сделал вот так,спасибо вам.

Comment: @Adingame пожалуйста)